# Twitter authentication with Javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-oauth

I want to get an access_token according to this documentation http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/oauth/request_token. I use javascript.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "json",
    data: {
        oauth_consumer_key: "DFwQqCnOTaYVbZQdBFqpR",
        oauth_signature_method: "HMAC-SHA1",
        oauth_timestamp: parseInt((new Date()).getTime() / 1000),
        oauth_nonce: "R" + parseInt((new Date()).getTime() / 1000),
        oauth_version: "1.0"
    },
    success: function (data) {
        debugger;
    },
    error: function (a, b, c) {
        debugger;
    }
});
```

But it does not work at all. Always return error, never success.

Comment: Please indent your code with four spaces instead of adding HTML tags.

Comment: Hi Alexander.  You can use 4 spaces (or the {} button in the question entry form) to format your code to be more readable, as I have done so above.  Also, html br elements are not necessary (and are in fact ignored)

Comment: Also, please define "does not work" - what behavior, exactly, are you seeing?

Comment: Maybe a stupid suggestion, but just to be sure; Are you sure you have included jQuery in your HTML as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not signing your request. You can read a more in depth direction on how to sign an OAuth reqeust on [dev.twitter.com](https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth#request-token). You will likely want to use a [JavaScript library](http://oauth.net/code/) to generate oauth_signature.

Answer (score 3):

Check user login & signup provided by Twitter's @Anywhere JavaScript library. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/anywhere/welcome#login-signup

That may be exactly what you want, much easier to use than the raw OAuth.

Comment: attached URL is no more working, please Update with newer one

Answer (score 0):

You're probably calling this script outside the `api.twitter.com` domain. Try with `dataType: "jsonp"`.

Comment: It has not helped. Response says: Failed to validate oauth signature and token.

Comment: "b" and "c" are empty. "a" has parameter error="errror". that is all

Comment: In firebug at the Net tab I see the status of the request. It is "401 Unauthorized"